# Do you need port forwarding to use SSH from your Pi anywhere?

Tags: pi-4, ssh, port-forwarding

I wanted to use my control my Pi via SSH from anywhere, and all the tutorials online I see for doing this require port forwarding. Is there any way to do this without using port forwarding?

Comment: `is there a way?` has a `yes` answer most of the time

Comment: could you be more specific? are there any websites or programs I would need to download to get this working? I can't seem to find it in any youtube tutorials or anywhere on StackExchange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about RPi. But to answer your question: Of course there is `another way`. One way is to get a [public IP address](https://www.avast.com/c-ip-address-public-vs-private) for your Pi. Another way is to set up a dynamic IP address for your RPi, and then configure your gateway/router/firewall to pass traffic through to your RPi. I'm sure there are others. Also - please do some homework before posting such questions.

Comment: `could you be more specific?` ... you asked a specific question `Is there any way to do this without using port forwarding?` ... the specific answer to that question is `yes` ... you asked if a solution exists ... you did not ask what a solution is  ... personally, I would ask the `how to do ... ?`, which asks for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no. perhaps.

To access the Pi's ssh port, it needs to be accessible. From the whole Internet, if you want to access it from anywhere.

In general, the Pi is connected to your internal LAN (either cabled or Wifi). That means that the Pi is behind some sort of SOHO-router. And that SOHO-router needs to know that the ssh-packages must go to the Pi.

All SOHO-routers (at least all those I know) support some form of port forwarding. This is why you will see most tutorials instruct you to use that.

There are alternatives. For example: you can create a VPN from your client device to your SOHO-router, if that router supports it. The easiest would be OpenVPN, but IPSec works as well. And then you ssh over the VPN towards your Pi.

If you have no control whatsoever over your SOHO-router, then setting-up an intermediate node somewhere in some cloud would be an option. Let the Pi set-up a VPN to the intermediate node, set-up a VPN from your client to the intermediate node and let the node do the routing.

And there are probably many other options.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is allowed, so admin feel free to delete.  In many cases where a public IP is not granted (mobile networks, starlink, etc) port forwarding won't work.  Further port forwarding does create an attack surface, e.g. scannable from the internet and RPi and similar popular devices are often specifically targeted.

One option is to use a service, full disclosure I am part of remote.it - but with our service you can access your RPi remotely from anywhere and easily connect via ssh, VNC or whatever service you have installed.  Service is free for up to 5 endpoints, in non-commercial use cases

Comment: hey thanks, i actually got it to work with what I wanted to do. there are just some important text files on my pi that id like to access from my PC or iPhone. however I am having one issue. I'm finding that on the PC terminal after I connect to my pi the typing is very slow. it feels super sluggish and is not fast like it usually is. there's a delay of like 0.3 seconds after I press a key on my keyboard.  any way to fix this that you might know about?

Comment: hmm that's usually the upload speed, but honestly with just SSH that seems odd - especially if you are just using port forwarding

Comment: i'm not using port forwarding. i'm just using remote.it right now to connect to my pi from different places. do you think it might help for me to disable network address translation on my router?